# System tray shows standard WiFi icon while VPN connected

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn

Normally, when I connect to my VPN the WiFi icon in the system tray changes to what I believe is the wired network icon. See images below for example images.

Wifi: [image: WiFi]

Wired: [image: Wired]

Recently the icon is no longer changing and stays as a WiFi icon. Running leak tests against a couple of sites in my browser shows no apparent issues and suggests my VPN connection is behaving normally.

If I remember right, when connected to my VPN previously, hovering over the icon would say router name - Internet access, Unidentified network (TAP?) - Internet access. Now it says the reverse.

If I go into network properties the TAP-Windows connection shows "Connected to unknown network, no traffic" while the WiFi connection shows "Connected to Internet / Connected to unknown network". Other connections all show disconnected.

**Some background info on network settings**

- Had VirtualBox installed which changes network settings. Present for a long time and didn't affect issue but removed.
- Previously had Hyper-V running which changes network settings. Present for a long time and didn't affect issue but removed a while ago.
- Installed Wireshark and WinPcap quite recently but removed. Recent enough that it may tie into issue but both removed.

**Steps taken**

- Removed VirtualBox, VPN client software, TAP-Windows
- Disabled on-board wired adapter on motherboard
- Updated driver for wireless adapter (as I was doing this as Administrator with VPN connected the system tray icon changed to the wired connection but prompted for reboot to continue install - back to WiFi icon when Windows restarted)
- Reset network using Open Network and Internet settings -> Network reset
- Set up the VPN client (with TAP-Windows) again and no difference

**My question**

Should I be concerned about the icon not changing? Could some of my traffic be bypassing the VPN or any other privacy issue I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you make any headway with this problem?

Comment: Not really. The icon tends to change as expected a lot of the time now but occasionally doesn't. Also had the problem appear on other PCs. It started around the time of a Windows update that was reported to be causing network problems for some people and I suspect it's related to that. My own attempts led me to suspect an issue with [InterfaceMetric](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric) as it kept changing and seemed to tie in with icon status changing, but I have next to no experience with that side of things.

Answer (score 0):

"Typically, the interface metric gives preference to a particular interface, such as using wired if both wired and wireless are available."

-I assume this is the root cause of the icon changing with little reason behind its change.

"The order in which adapters appear in a list is determined by the IPv4 or IPv6 interface metric."

-Perhaps exploring the issue in PowerShell may allow one to manually change the interface metric. If someone has more time, I'd love to see this problem answered.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396